# (Python) Summing two linked lists where each node is an integer. Attribute error

Tags: python, class, linked-list, attributeerror

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, node = None):
        self.head = node
        self.length = 0
    
    def InsertNode(self, data):
        newNode = Node()
        newNode.data = data
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode
        self.length += 1
    
    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp != None:
            print(temp.data, end = " ")
            temp = temp.next

    

class AddingListNumbers:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, list1, list2):
        if list1 == None:
            return list2
        if list2 == None:
            return list1
        len1 = len2 = 0
        head = list1.head
        while head != None:
            len1 += 1
            head = head.next
        head = list2.head
        while head != None:
            len2 += 1
            head = head.next
        if len1 > len2:
            shorter = list2
            longer = list1
        else:
            shorter = list1
            longer = list2
        sum = None
        carry = 0
        while shorter != None:
            value = shorter.data + longer.data + carry
            carry = value / 10
            value -= carry * 10
            if sum == None:
                sum = Node(value)
                result = sum
            else:
                sum.next = Node(value)
                sum = sum.next
            shorter = shorter.next
            longer = longer.next
        while longer != None:
            value = longer.data + carry
            carry = value / 10
            value -= carry * 10
            sum.next = Node(value)
            sum = sum.next
            longer = longer.next
        if carry != 0:
            sum.next = Node(carry)
        return result

linkedlist = LinkedList()
linkedlist.InsertNode(19)
linkedlist.InsertNode(14)
linkedlist.InsertNode(11)
linkedlist.InsertNode(9)
linkedlist.InsertNode(6)
linkedlist.InsertNode(5)

linkedlist2 = LinkedList()
linkedlist2.InsertNode(17)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(16)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(13)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(6)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(2)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(1)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(24)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(3)
linkedlist2.InsertNode(11)

list3 = LinkedList()
ResultList = AddingListNumbers()
list3.next = ResultList.addTwoNumbers(linkedlist, linkedlist2)
list3.printList()
```

I have created Node and LinkedList classes and then another class AddingListNumbers for adding the list number.
I am getting an error message:

value = shorter.data + longer.data + carry
AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'data'

I don't understand how to debug this one. How to handle attribute errors?

[**Below is the image of the error message.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViJUp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this section:

```
if len1 > len2:
    shorter = list2 # should be list2.head instead
    longer = list1 # should be list1.head instead
else:
    shorter = list1 # should be list1.head instead
    longer = list2 # should be list2.head instead
```

With that said, however, this code can be optimised to traverse the lists only once. In this implementation you're first finding the shorter list and then adding while the shorter list is traversed. It can be done in single traversal as:

1. Repeat these steps while list1 is traversed OR list2 is traversed completely
2. Add data from node of list1, if it exists, or add 0
3. Add data from node of list2, if it exists, or add 0
4. Add carry to the above sum.
5. Calculate divmod of the sum and re-assign carry and sum.
6. Move pointers ahead, if next nodes are present.

The resultant list will have sum of the lists.

Comment: That did it. Thanks, brother.

Comment: @UMDowney Please mark the answer as accepted if this worked for you.